# Dispatch anidados

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Necesito de su ayuda, estoy trabajando en una aplicacion la cual consta de un dispatch y la misma usa variables que deberian pasar a ser dispatch. y que las mismas no deben pisar las que ya estan siendo usada en el codigo. Podrian ayudarme por favor. Este es el codigo:
Los reducer ya se definieron, pero no encuentro la forma eficiente de dar salida a su uso.

No encontre ninguna solucion eficiente. Y me quede sin ideas.

```
    dispatchLoadPostCreateDialog({
        type: "LOAD_POST_CREATE_DIALOG",
        payload: {
            showDependency: "actualizaVersion",
            apiUrl: `${baseUrl}/liberacion/`,
            type: "dialog",
            invisibleDynamic: 'idIncidenciaActividad',
           (este deberia ser un dispatch ->) dialogsData: {
                principal: {
                    title: `Liberación de incidencia`,
                    description: "la liberación de la incidencia"
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que estas tratando de usar el dispatch para enviar una accion a tus reducers. sin embargo estas tratando de pasar una variable llamada dialodsData como parte de la accion y quieres que esta sea un variable dispatch en lugar de un objeto estático-
Si lo que quieres es que los dialogsData sea un dispatch, lo que necesitas es definir una accion separada para ello.

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { loadPostCreateDialog, setDialogsData } from "./actions";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleDispatch = () => {
    dispatch(
      loadPostCreateDialog({
        showDependency: "actualizaVersion",
        apiUrl: `${baseUrl}/liberacion/`,
        type: "dialog",
        invisibleDynamic: "idIncidenciaActividad",
      })
    );

    dispatch(
      setDialogsData({
        principal: {
          title: "Liberación de incidencia",
          description: "la liberación de la incidencia",
        },
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleDispatch}>Dispatch</button>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

he creado dos acciones separadas: loadPostCreateDialog y setDialogsData. la primera se encarga de enviar la carga util principal de la accion, mientras que la segunda se encarga de establecer los datos del dialogo y posteriormente en el componente MyComponent, utiliza el useDispatch hook para obtener la funcion dispatch y se llama a ambas acciones dentro de la funcion handleDispatch.